Why doesn't db.collection() in my Node.js-MongoDB function run at the correct time?
I have the following code using a MongoClient getting called twice:
async function readWhileRunning(dbName, collectionName, query, projection) {

    const collection = await getCollection(dbName, collectionName);

    console.log("Here3")

    return await collection.find(query, projection).toArray();
}

async function getCollection(dbName, collectionName) {

    console.log("Here1")

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    console.log("Here2")

    return db.collection(collectionName);
}

For some reason it produces the following output (alongside an empty array of database records):
Here1
Here2
Here1
Here2
Here3
Here3

Looks like db.collection(collectionName) refuses to run before everything else is done. I specified every function as async and every call with await. What am I doing wrong?

How are you actually invoking these functions. You've only listed function definitions here.

Does it matter? The whole function call is long and complicated. It just searches for, in this instance, 2 records in the database, that's why it's running twice. I'm just asking what makes the program leave my getCollection() function in half and start over with the second chain of calls, while the first is not even finished yet.

The reason why I ask is because I dont see why the code you've listed behaves the way that it does. There are no asynchronous operations in getCollection so everything should just run synchronously. So maybe the answer is in what you have not shown, i.e the actual calls to readWhileRunning.

As an aside, do you really need a separate function to get the collection.
Wouldn't it be more prudent just to put everything in readWhileRunning? Seems simpler...

If that's the case, then looks like I'm in a more complex debugging than expected. Thank you though, that's also information in and of itself. Also, to answer you, I write seperate functions for seperate tasks, so no function does too many things. I was taught this back in the day as a best practice.

The code inside getCollection function is not an async (there are no awaits inside) and if you delete async keyword before getCollection and call it like that:
const collection = getCollection(dbName, collectionName);

your output will be:
Here1
Here2
Here3
Here1
Here2
Here3


Assertion about your snippet. You call readWhileRunning 2 times synchronously like that:
    readWhileRunning();
    readWhileRunning();

When you make getCollection async and call it with await inside readWhileRunning, execution of first readWhileRunning is blocked. Then second call of readWhileRunning starts early than first call is done.
But if you call readWhileRunning 2 times async like that:
(async function () {
    await readWhileRunning();
    await readWhileRunning();
})()


Then you current code snippet with await getCollection() should log a proper order of messages.
So comment from @Sello Mkantjwa about function invocation was very fair.
